# What is "quota_max" and "quota_remaining" in api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users API?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, api

I am trying to fetch user info using following API.

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{id}?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

It returns data like : I want to know what is "quota_max" and "quota_remaining" for?

```
    {
      "items": [
         {{All User Data}}
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "quota_max": 300,
      "quota_remaining": 250
    }
```

Comment: you might want to go through https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`quota_max` is the maximum number of API calls allowed per day per IP-address.

`quota_remaining` is the number of API calls you have remaining for this day from this IP-address.

Once you've exhausted that quota any API call will return you an error.

By default everyone is granted 300 API calls per day per IP-address. To increase that quota to 10,000 calls, register your app and obtain a key. If you're on a shared IP-address you better also authenticate your app with a no_expiry key.

See [How API keys work](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work) and [Rate Limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Worth noting that you are also [not supposed to call the API more than 30 times within 5 seconds](https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits) or even more precise: [not more than 30 times per second](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Comment: the limit is now 30 calls per second https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: The limit is still 300 when I check my [personal api SO user](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1705829?&site=stackoverflow) address, but probably not per day but per hour without api key.